# Convertendo mp3 para ogg em php no joomla

Tags: php, joomla, ogg

Estou tentando converter um arquivo mp3 para ogg usando o ffmpeg.exe o problema é que o Joomla não me deixa executar um arquivo externo, mesmo no mesmo diretório.

```
<?php exec('C:\\path\\to\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i file.mp3 -acodec libvorbis file.ogg'); ?>
```

Esse código não retorna nenhum erro, ele só não executa.
Existe alguma outra forma para executar o ffmpeg.exe dentro do Joomla?
Ou existe uma forma de converter direto via php que o Joomla aceite?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui executar e converter o arquivo, porém somente no mesmo diretório onde o **ffmpeg.exe** está, depois tive que move-lo.
Antes de fazer a chamada **exec** ativei o **safe_mode** e adicionei o diretório onde estou trabalhando e funcionou.

```
ini_set('safe_mode',true);
ini_set('safe_mode_exec_dir','C:\\path\\to\\');
exec('C:\\path\\to\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i file.mp3 -acodec libvorbis file.ogg');
```

Não sei se essa é a melhor forma, porém assim funcionou. Movi o arquivo utilizando o **JFile::move()**.

Answer (score 1):

O `safe_mode` esta em desuso no PHP5.3 e foi removido no PHP5.4

O caminho mais correto é utilizar a função `exec` com `$output` e passar os argumentos com `escapeshellcmd` (no caso do Windows), se for linux/like-unix use o comando `escapeshellarg`

Exemplo:

```
<?php
$comando = 'C:\\path\\to\\ffmpeg.exe';
$argumentos = escapeshellcmd('-y -i file.mp3 -acodec libvorbis file.ogg');

exec($comando . ' ' . $argumentos, $output);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```